# Как сделать 2 условия в Apache — Rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Коллеги, приветствую!

С `mod_rewrite` редко сталкиваюсь, появилась задача сделать редирект при выполнению одновременно двух условий:

1. Адрес домена равно `domain.com`
2. Адрес страницы не равно `domain.com/f/s.php`

Пытаюсь юзать

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_URI } !^domain.com/f/s.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но оно редиректит даже если адрес страницы совпадает с `domain.com/f/s.php`
подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего сделать.

Собственно даже 2 вопроса:

1. Как 2 условия прописать?
2. Как написать условие страницы не равно `domain.com/f/s.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Ваша проблема в том, что в `SCRIPT_URI` попадает весь URI запроса, включая протокол. Учтите этот момент, или используйте `REQUEST_URI`.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Еще одна полезная ссылка с примером что находится в системных переменных окружения:
http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/RewriteCond.php
И не забывайте про слэш в начале пути.